# Is "Install for this user only/Install for all users" functionality supported by CMake?

Tags: cmake

Installing some application usually requires admin rights. To try something for the first time, it would be advantageous to install it in the user's own directory, with user's rights. Is it somehow supported by CMake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**:

With CMake, you can only specify *where* you install your targets. If you install it in your own directory, you will be only one able to access it, while everyone will be able to access it if you install it as an admin in some system location (`/usr/local` in Linux, `C:\Program Files` in Windows, etc.).

If you want easy access to the program, further files must be installed in order to have a shortcut on the Desktop or in the Start Menu.
Programs that suggest to install something for one user or for all users normally also install such "shortcuts".

As far as I know, this should be possible to achieve with CMake, but you would need to specify the locations of the shortcuts manually, and this is different for different platforms.